# NetworkOnMainThreadException even after subscribing to schedulers.io()

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, kotlin-android-extensions

I tried to practice my skills, and tried to mimic networking using RX java.

But when I try to execute my code, I am getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, despite having used `Schedulers.io()` thread.

I wanted to separate the code into three methods, but it's not working. I already replaced all `.just()` with `.fromCallable{}` but it's still not working

Here is my code:

```
fun String.post(authorization: String, params: HashMap<String, String>): Single<out Response> {
    try {
        val url = URL(this)
        val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
        connection.apply {
            requestMethod = "POST"
            addRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization.sha1())
            addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            doOutput = true
            DataOutputStream(connection.outputStream).use {
                it.write(params.toUrlEncoded().toByteArray())
            }

            val single = when (connection.responseCode) {
                200, 201 -> {
                    val body = connection.inputStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
                    Single.fromCallable { DataResponse(HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK, body) }
                }
                else -> {
                    val message = connection.errorStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
                    Single.fromCallable { ErrorResponse(connection.responseCode, message) }
                }
            }
            connection.disconnect()
            return single
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return Single.fromCallable { ErrorResponse(500, e.message.toString()) }
    }
} 

fun downloadImage(authorization: String, params: HashMap<String, String>): Single<Any> {
        return (BuildConfig.BASE_URL + IMAGE_URL).post(authorization, params).flatMap {
            when (it) {
                is DataResponse -> {
                    val json = JSONObject(it.body)
                    if (json.has("image")) {
                        return@flatMap Single.fromCallable { ImageData(json.getString("image")) }
                    } else {
                        return@flatMap Single.error<HttpException>(HttpException(-1, ""))
                    }
                }
                is ErrorResponse -> {
                    return@flatMap Single.error<HttpException>(HttpException(it.code, it.message))
                }
                else -> {
                    return@flatMap Single.error<HttpException>(HttpException(-1, ""))
                }
            }
        }
    } 

repository.downloadImage(password, hashMapOf("username" to login)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeBy({
                it.printStackTrace()
            }, {
                _imageData.postValue(it as ImageData)
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is weird but I managed to solve it by removing the Single() wrapping class from String.post() function. So the working code :

```
fun String.post(authorization: String, params: HashMap<String, String>): Response {
    try {
        val url = URL(this)
        val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
        connection.apply {
            requestMethod = "POST"
            addRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization.sha1())
            addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            doOutput = true
            DataOutputStream(connection.outputStream).use {
                it.write(params.toUrlEncoded().toByteArray())
            }

            val response = when (connection.responseCode) {
                200, 201 -> {
                    val body = connection.inputStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
                    DataResponse(HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK, body)
                }
                else -> {
                    val message = connection.errorStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
                     ErrorResponse(connection.responseCode, message)
                }
            }
            connection.disconnect()
            return response
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return ErrorResponse(500, e.message.toString())
    }
} 


fun downloadImage(authorization: String, params: HashMap<String, String>): Single<Any> {
        return Single.fromCallable { (BuildConfig.BASE_URL + IMAGE_URL).post(authorization, params) }.flatMap {
            when (it) {
                is DataResponse -> {
                    val json = JSONObject(it.body)
                    if (json.has("image")) {
                        return@flatMap Single.fromCallable { ImageData(json.getString("image")) }
                    } else {
                        return@flatMap Single.error<HttpException>(HttpException(-1, ""))
                    }
                }
                is ErrorResponse -> {
                    return@flatMap Single.error<HttpException>(HttpException(it.code, it.message))
                }
                else -> {
                    return@flatMap Single.error<HttpException>(HttpException(-1, ""))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```